# DatePicker Styling in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I require to use a date picker for a windows phone 8.1 project. I need to apply customs styles such as changing the border, background and display date.

I tried using DayFormat, MonthFormat properties in XAML but I found/realized that they are ignored on the phone platform.

How should I go about this?
For example I need to display the date as "23 March 2015" in the date picker display. Also provide a gray background and remove border.

Comment: tried this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn308514.aspx

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to tell. Those formats are not supported on the phone. Even if I add the tags, nothing happens. And yes, that is ridiculous.